# Need help on calling selected html menu name inside UI.r

Tags: r

I need help in getting/displaying the selected html menu name inside ui.r.

Below are my scripts

```
ui.r

library(shinydashboard)
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        dashboardPage(skin = c("blue"),
            dashboardHeader(title = "R Tools"),
               dashboardSidebar(
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                     menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")))
                    ),
               dashboardBody(
                  getTool("navmenuname"),
                  print(input.navmenuname),
                  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.navmenuname=='Barchart",
                  print(input.navmenuname)
                 )    
              )
        )
    )
)
global.r
library(shiny)
getTool <- function(inputId) {
tagList(
 tags$html(includeHTML('navbar.html'))
  )
}
```

Comment: Please post your full reproducible code. I cant see your server.R here. For future posts refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: # server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  }
)